# Wordpress= is_author(admin) or Is_entry or similar?

Tags: wordpress

I need a function that returns true when the author is an admin or an editor or of a certain role.

I can't use is_single because I have set up a forum and there are a million singles out there and I need a different layout for THE posts (the ones written in the blog by admins and editors) than from the forum entries

Comment: See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5202/a-function-that-returns-true-when-the-author-is-a-certain-role-is-authoradmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you create an `author.php` page you can customize the way `the authors` page looks.

see more here http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates#Sample_Template_File

Is this what you are looking for?